# Display SQL Data on a PhoneGap App - Possible Using URLs?

Tags: php, android, ios, mysql, cordova

I'm building a web application using PHP & MySQL. A user profile displays MySQL data using a select query like so:

```
SELECT a.name_first,a.name_last,b.bio_category,b.bio_short,b.bio_full,b.profile_img
FROM stars_login a, stars_data_bio b
WHERE a.id_s=b.id_s
AND a.id_s='$select_id'
```

The `$select_id` variable is defined using `?id=` in the URL like so:

`http://localhost/public_html/profile/profile.php?id=1`

I'm also looking at turning the web application into a phone app. I don't have much experience creating native apps as I'm more of a web designer.
I have however used Adobe PhoneGap before (cheating kinda, I know).

**My question:** is there a way to display a user profile in an Adobe PhoneGap app using a similar method to my exploded URLs in PHP?

Eg: there will be a search bar on my PhoneGap App home screen, where a user can search for a username. When they hit the search button they will be redirected to the profile view (similar to the `profile.php` page on my website). The PhoneGap profile page will then show the SQL data for the corresponding user.

I'm not sure if this is possible, but if it is, could you let me know how to go about it?

Also - how would I display the data that is stored server side on my local app?

I'm fairly new to all of this - I'm 18 and self teaching for a personal project of mine. All help is appreciated!

Comment: You would probably want to get the data from your server as JSON. You would then have to create the HTML to display the data based on the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in your Hybrid app:

1. Create an HTML form which will serve as the front end to user
2. Use AJAX to send input from the user to your server
3. Process whatever pass parameter/s in that ajax request (such as the query you mentioned).
4. Return the result as json/jsonp then display the result back to the front end (no.1)

Comment: So the AJAX would be executed within the PhoneGap App?

Comment: Yes. JS and AJAX codes can be inside your PhoneGap App.